# System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject due to no records in SOQL

Tags: apex, unit-test, exception

Below is the code written by someone else .I need to rectify this in short time as its deployment time. Any help would be helpful for me.I know code is written badly. I also know error is because there are no records to be assigned. So how can I avoid this error? Error is at line below:

```
Id pbEntry=[select Id from pricebookentry where currencyIsoCode='EUR' and isActive=true and Pricebook2Id=:pb.Id and Product2Id=:directSalesRule.Product__c limit
```

Here's the test:

```
public static testmethod void test_approval() {
        PriceBook2 pb=[Select Id From Pricebook2 where name='Volcano Europe Price Book'];
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(Name='Test', Opportunity_Country__c='Belgium', currencyIsoCode='EUR', StageName='Evaluation', CloseDate=System.today(), Pricebook2Id=pb.Id );
        insert opp;

        // Direct Sales Testing

        Direct_Sales_Rules__c directSalesRule=[select Product__c,Country__c, SD_Amount__c, RSM_Amount__c, FD_Amount__c  from Direct_Sales_Rules__c where country__c ='Belgium' limit 1];
        Id pbEntry=[select Id from pricebookentry where currencyIsoCode='EUR' and isActive=true and Pricebook2Id=:pb.Id and Product2Id=:directSalesRule.Product__c limit 1].Id;
        OpportunityLineItem l = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=opp.Id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=20, PriceBookEntryId=pbEntry);
        insert l;   
        l.UnitPrice=directSalesRule.SD_Amount__c;
        update l;
        l.UnitPrice=directSalesRule.RSM_Amount__c;
        update l;
        l.UnitPrice=directSalesRule.FD_Amount__c;
        update l;
        l.UnitPrice=directSalesRule.RSM_Amount__c-1;
        update l;
        // Channel Sales Testing
        Channel_Sales_Rules__c channelSalesRule = [select Product__c,Distributor__c, SD_Amount__c from Channel_Sales_Rules__c where Distributor__c ='H.S. Srl' limit 1];
        opp.Distributor__c ='H.S. Srl';
        pbEntry=[select Id from pricebookentry where currencyIsoCode='EUR' and isActive=true and Pricebook2Id=:pb.Id and Product2Id=:channelSalesRule.Product__c limit 1].Id;
        update opp;
        l = new OpportunityLineItem(OpportunityId=opp.Id, Quantity=1, UnitPrice=20, PriceBookEntryId=pbEntry);
        l.UnitPrice=channelSalesRule.SD_Amount__c-1;
        insert  l;
        l.UnitPrice=channelSalesRule.SD_Amount__c;
        update l;

    }
```

Comment: you can simply list for query result.. if list is not empty then list[0] use for single record

Comment: Related reading: [Why Are Data Silos Important in Unit Tests?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122445/why-are-data-silos-important-in-unit-tests)

Comment: Also, that's just not how unit tests are supposed to work. It looks like the developer wanted to test every single piece of related functionality in one go, and there are at least five or six different triggers at play. Without a single assertion!

Comment: @ratan-List is empty.So how to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is like [@Ratan](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/18731/ratan) has said.

Replace the following:

```
Id pbEntry=[select Id from pricebookentry where currencyIsoCode='EUR' and isActive=true and Pricebook2Id=:pb.Id and Product2Id=:directSalesRule.Product__c limit 1].Id;
```

With:

```
Id pbEntry;
List<Id> listOfPriceBookEntries = [select Id from pricebookentry where currencyIsoCode='EUR' and isActive=true and Pricebook2Id=:pb.Id and Product2Id=:directSalesRule.Product__c limit 1];
if( ! listOfPriceBookEntries.isEmpty() ) 
    pbEntry = listOfPriceBookEntries[0].Id;
```

This will get the Id, however in the scenario you currently have, the next line won't work as expected due to `PriceBookEntryId=pbEntry`.

You've probably got a bigger issue around the PriceBook2 default pricebook.  You may need to look into the `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` method, depending on what's required here.

Comment: It worked.i was not using null check as it was throwing me index out of bound error.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Term Solution**: ensure the data exists.

**Long Term Solution**: massively expand your test suite.

---

**Short Term**

You can take advantage of the `@TestSetup` annotation to do some data creation to ensure your query will return some data.

```
@TestSetup
static void setup()
{
    Product2 product = new Product2(/*data*/);
    insert product;

    Direct_Sales_Rules__c rule = new Direct_Sales_Rules__c(/*data*/);
    insert rule;

    PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(/*data*/);
    insert pbe;
}
```

Now you don't need to guess if any matching records are in the system. If you use `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` then you don't even need `SeeAllData=true`.

**Long Term**

The term "unit" in `Unit Testing` means you should be measuring and verifying one (small) cohesive unit of code. Testing multiple triggers in a go is like using a shotgun where a scalpel would be more appropriate. Also, we commonly call test methods without any assertions `Smoke Tests` instead. They can only fail if they hit a hard exception (what you observed). But they don't actually verify if *any* of the functionality does what it's supposed to. Your test suite is your contract. Protect yourself with it.