# Test Error- Changing from List to Id - List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: soql, unit-test, query, failing-tests, id

In my test class I have a query:

```
Id oppId = [SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Credit_Review__c LIMIT 1].Opportunity__c;
```

when I use query editor: `SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Credit_Review__c LIMIT 1` I get back the correct result.

But when I run my test I am getting back that there is no data. Does this have something to do with me changing it from a list to an Id with `.Opportunity__c`?

Comment: Are you actually setting up a `Credit_Review__c` record in your test?

Comment: To expand on Adrian's point, tests are isolated from data that is already in an org; you need to add the data in the test.

Comment: @KeithC I did have hard coded data and all tests would pass with 93% coverage. But when I would deploy it to prod, I would get `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` for the mentioned SOQL line. It was originally ` SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Credit_Review__c WHERE Credit_Review__c.Id = '1234567547654' Do I have to make a CSV file and import the data to prod? I have never had a problem with hard coding the data in test before and am not sure what to do

Comment: See also: [Why Are Data Silos Important in Unit Tests?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122445/why-are-data-silos-important-in-unit-tests)

Answer (score 2):

Test classes do not have data by default, so there are no records when you attempt to query.

I would recommend two things:

1) Read [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm), [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_best_practices.htm) and [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_utility_classes.htm) article. It'll help you on how to create data within your test class.

2) Create an error-handling method to ensure that, in case that no
    records exist in `Credit_Review__c` then the application does not
    throw an error. I would simply split the line into two, like the
    following example (there are multiple ways to do it, this is just
    one)

```
Credit_Review__c cr = [SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Credit_Review__c LIMIT 1]; 
if (cr != null) {    
   Id oppId = cr.Opportunity__c; 
}
```

Comment: what are your thoughts on using `seeAllData= true`

Comment: when I do this, I am able to pass the tests with 93% coverage but am unable to deploy to prod

Comment: I am adamantly against using `seeAllData= true`, It is not only bad practice, but your tests will simply fail if the destination org doesn't have the proper data, or it is in the wrong state.

Comment: It is not very hard to create data that is specific to your tests. The investment is well worth it.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like you suggest creating the CVS and making it specific to my test.

Comment: Your test code should create it, then it doesn't matter whether it's in prod or not, since the test will contain its own data. Did you read the link I enclosed?

Comment: This link is better: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_utility_classes.htm

Comment: Thank you, after some more research, I still can't just create the data in my test class. I think the issue is coming from my web call out. I will update if I get any close to the answer!