# TestClass for throwing Exception while testing Trigger

Tags: trigger, unit-test, query, error, exception

I writing my first Testclass to test my first Trigger and encountered some error.

I have written a trigger to update the Phone number of all contacts when its Accounts Phone number is updated. Its working fine when I change the phone number of Account via UI, its updating the related Contacts Phone number using trigger.

But when I try to test it via Testclass by updating the Phone number of Account via code, its showing some error while running.

```
Error: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Stack Trace: Class.UpdateAccountPhoneUnitTest.AccountPhoneUpate: line 5, column 1
```

[image]
Can someone please help me to understand what went wrong inside my TestClass and how it can be fixed?

Comment: A search on the error would have produced many many results on the subject....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you haven't created test data in the test class. When you run the query, there are no Accounts named "Acme Corporation" in the database, so the query comes back empty, and the assignment to the `accountToUpdate` variable fails.

You should add something to your test class like:

```
public static @testSetup void setupTest{
    insert new Account(name='Acme Corporation');
}
```

Comment: But I have Account named "Acme Corporation" in the database, I have run the query in Workbench and I have pasted in the screenshot above.

Comment: During test execution, if you haven't set `SeeAllData=True`, that data won't be visible.

Comment: @RobertThomas There was actually a featured question on this topic just a few days ago: [Why Are Data Silos Important in Unit Tests?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122445/why-are-data-silos-important-in-unit-tests)

Comment: no problem​​​​​​‌​‌​‌​‌​