# Test Class - Issue

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, code-coverage

**Test Class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    public class ImplementationControllerTest
    {

    public static testmethod void test1()
    {

    Implementation__c i = [SELECT Id,Implementation_Status__c,Name,Opportunity__c,OwnerId,Adviser__c,Client_Name__c,Client_Number__c,Partner_s_Name__c,Client_Type__c,Notes__c,Managed_Fund_Status__c FROM Implementation__c LIMIT 1];

    ApexPages.StandardController stdCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(i);
    ImplementationController impcontroller = new ImplementationController(stdCon);

    impcontroller.saveImp();
    impcontroller.exitImp();

    }

    public static testmethod void test2()
    {

    Implementation__History ih =  [SELECT ID,NewValue,OldValue,ParentId,Field,CreatedDate,CreatedById FROM Implementation__History LIMIT 1];

    Implementation__c i = [SELECT Id,Implementation_Status__c,Name,Opportunity__c,OwnerId,Adviser__c,Client_Name__c,Client_Number__c,Partner_s_Name__c,Client_Type__c,Notes__c,Managed_Fund_Status__c FROM Implementation__c WHERE Id = :ih.ParentId];


    ApexPages.StandardController stdCon = new ApexPages.StandardController(i);
    ImplementationController impcontroller = new ImplementationController(stdCon);

    impcontroller.saveImp();
    impcontroller.exitImp();

    }



    }
```

**Controller Class**

```
public class ImplementationController {

    public ApexPages.standardController st_controller;
   // public Implementation__c i{get;set;}
    public Implementation__c implementation{get; set;}
    public Implementation_Status__c CancelledStatus = Implementation_Status__c.getValues('Cancelled'); // Cancelled
    public Service_Enquiry_Settings__c ses_exit_url = Service_Enquiry_Settings__c.getValues('ExitURLImp');
    public List<String> li_Implementation_Nav_Bar{get; set;}
    public List<WrapperHistoryList> WrapperHistories{get;set;}

    public ImplementationController (ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
     st_controller = stdController;
     implementation = getImplementation(st_controller.getId());
     li_Implementation_Nav_Bar = getImplementationNavBar(implementation);
     //implementationhistories = getImplementationHistory(implementation);
      WrapperHistories = getImplementationHistory(implementation);  
        }

    public class WrapperHistoryList{
        public String lbl{get;set;}
        public Implementation__History ImplementationHistory{get;set;}

    }

    public String GetLabel(String fname)
    {
      if(fname != null)
      {
        String type='Implementation__c';
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.SObjectType leadSchema = schemaMap.get(type);
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = leadSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        return fieldMap.get(fname).getDescribe().getLabel();
      }
      else
      return null;
    }

    public List<WrapperHistoryList> getImplementationHistory(Implementation__c impe)
    {
        List<WrapperHistoryList> wlist = new List<WrapperHistoryList>();

        List<Implementation__History> imphis = [SELECT ID,NewValue,OldValue,ParentId,Field,CreatedDate,CreatedById FROM Implementation__History WHERE ParentId= :impe.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
        if(imphis.size()>0)
        {
            //return imphis;
            for(Implementation__History i : imphis)
            {
                WrapperHistoryList w = new WrapperHistoryList();
                w.ImplementationHistory = i;
                w.lbl = GetLabel(i.Field);
                wlist.add(w);
            }
            return wlist;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

   public Implementation__c getImplementation(String ImpId){

        Implementation__c imp = new Implementation__c();
        String queryStr = 'Select ' + CommonUsedClass.sObjectGetAllFields(imp).trim() + ' From Implementation__c Where Id = : ImpId';
        try{
           imp = Database.query(queryStr);     
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('****** Querying Service Enquiry Exception: ' + e.getMessage()); 
        }
        return imp;
    }

    public List<String> getImplementationNavBar(Implementation__c impe){
        List<String> li_nav = new List<String>();
        for(SelectOption option : CommonUsedClass.getPicklistValue('Implementation__c', 'Implementation_Status__c')){
            // Active Nav Bar - without 'Lost' status
            if(impe.Implementation_Status__c != CancelledStatus.Status_Name__c){
                if(option.getValue() != CancelledStatus.Status_Name__c){
                    li_nav.add(option.getLabel());    
                }                 
            }
            else{
                li_nav.add(option.getLabel());
            }

        }
        return li_nav;
    }

  public PageReference saveImp(){

       System.debug('~~~ Before Update'); 
        update implementation;
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + ses_exit_url.URL__c);
        return page;

    }

    public PageReference exitImp(){
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + ses_exit_url.URL__c);
        return page;
    }


}
```

**Issue :**

My test class fails in the method "test2()".
I get the following output

```
Time Started    27/02/2017 2:03 PM
Class   ImplementationControllerTest
Method Name test2
Pass/Fail   Fail
Error Message   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Stack Trace Class.ImplementationController.GetLabel: line 33, column 1
Class.ImplementationController.getImplementationHistory: line 51, column 1
Class.ImplementationController.<init>: line 16, column 1
Class.ImplementationControllerTest.test2: line 27, column 1
```

I understand that for some reason I am getting a null object error in GetLabel() method in ImplementationController.

I am not able to understand why it occurs though.

Because as you can see I am using Describes to get the metadata and the code is working as expected while rendering the VF but only the test method (test2()) is failing.

Can someone let me know what is wrong ?

Comment: Why you are using SeeAllData = True? Why not test data?

Comment: It is mainly to avoid creating the test records by myself

Comment: Test Data doesn't create any records in the org! And it is bad practice to use org data as the environment changes meaning from sandnbox to production your test class will fail if the record with specific condition is not available!
Please refer this link-: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods

Comment: Aaron - well worth reading this SFSE post and answers on mocking your test data http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122445/why-are-data-silos-important-in-unit-tests/122464#122464

Comment: If you just want the VF page to have access to the label, you can do it in the VF markup yourself: `{!$ObjectType.Implementation__c.fields.someFieldApiName.Label}`

Comment: One of the records you are grabbing has no value or an improper value for the field field

Comment: @AaronWilfred Instead of testing a string with a null, please use the provided function String.isEmpty(stringToTest). It'll prevent the null pointer exception (1) & it tests the null & the emptiness of the string (!= '') (2). Why not use it then ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm